# How to add line numbers for code in a WordPress.com web page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress.com

I am placing a small code snippet in a WordPress.com web page. WordPress.com provides a ["Code Block" option](https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/code-block/) for formatting code.

Is there a way to add line numbers to the code in this code block?

Comment: Line numbers are most useful when you need to refer to specific lines from the code.  For example, compilers will often say what line number cause a compiler error.   On websites, it is fairly rare to put line numbers on code blocks.   [so] has tons of code and doesn't number the lines.   Do you have a case in which you want to refer to the line numbers of the code in your blocks?

Comment: I want to explain code line by line in tutorials. So, I need to refer w.r.t. the line number during explanation. @StephenOstermiller

Comment: Please comment the reason for downvote if possbile as I am new to this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, it looks like WordPress.com's *SyntaxHighlighter Code Block* shows line numbers, whereas their *Code Block* does not. My understanding is that the *SyntaxHighlighter Code Block* is a fancier, more full-featured code block type that's built into WordPress.com.

See the *SyntaxHighlighter Code Block* documentation for more info:
https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/syntax-highlighter-code-block/

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at WP plugins to replace the default editor?  I personally have avoided the default editor for a couple of years.

A quick search of [code editors for Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/code+editor/) will give you many different editors.  Several of them have line number functionality.  However, you will want to make sure they all work with the current "block" technology of the new Gutenberg Editor (about 2 years old).

Here's one with a [screenshot](https://wordpress.org/plugins/html-editor-syntax-highlighter/#screenshots) of it's line numbers.

Whether they will specifically work inside of `code blocks` as opposed to `inline` as shown in the example would require testing.  The one shown in the screenshot specifically says it doesn't work with "blocks in the visual editor".